# When did 'the D' for penis come into common use?

Tags: etymology, slang

I had never heard of this until last year, but suddenly everyone on the internet is using it. I was wondering where it came from and why it took off so quickly.

eg.

> She wants the D.

Comment: ^Do you mean for 'Dick'?

Answer (score 3):

According to [knowyourmeme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/the-d):

> “The D” first made an appearance on the 2004 single “So Sexy” by American rapper Twista featuring R&B artist R. Kelly.

The entry for "the D" on Urban Dictionary was created in 2004 as well.

Though the use of the term became more widespread through Tumblr in 2012:

> ...following the viral spread of Give Her the Dick, an oddly phrased
>   comment that was originally posted on the adult website Pornhub
>
> Throughout 2012, the phrase “she wants the D” was mentioned in dozens of dating and relationship advice threads on Yahoo Answers and the Bodybuilding Forums.